# Active Directory Acquiring Locked/Unlocked status in a Windows Service

Tags: c#, active-directory, windows-services, windows-server-2012-r2

I am making a **Windows Service** that gets the Locked/Unlocked status of all Active Directory accounts in my local domain TRY.local.
Even though the account with the name user1 is locked, it gives **false** value for **IsAccountLocked()**.

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "TRY.local"))
{
    using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
    {
        foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
        {
            DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
            Library.WriteErrorLog("First Name: " + de.Properties["givenName"].Value);
            try{
                string name = (string)de.Properties["samaccountname"].Value;
                PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"TRY.local","CN="+name+",OU=Users,DC=TRY,DC=local","administrator","password");
                UserPrincipal usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, name);
                if(usr!=null){
                    Library.WriteErrorLog("IsAccountLockedOut\t"+usr.IsAccountLockedOut());
                }
                usr.Dispose();
                ctx.Dispose();
            }
        catch(Exception e){                                         
            Library.WriteErrorLog(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "TRY.local"))
{
    using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
    {
        foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
        {
            DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
            Library.WriteErrorLog("SAM Account Name : " + de.Properties["samaccountname"].Value);
            int uc = Convert.ToInt32(de.Properties["userAccountControl"][0]);
            const int ADS_LOCKOUT = 0x00000010;
            bool account_LockedOut = (uc & ADS_LOCKOUT)==ADS_LOCKOUT;
            Library.WriteErrorLog("IsAccountLockedOut : "+account_LockedOut);                                       
        }
    }
}
```

WriteErrorLog(string abc) writes abc to a textfile[image: It gives false even if the account is Locked]

[image: user1 is Locked]

I would be very grateful if I could get guidance on this issue as I am new to Active Directory.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to use the LOCKOUT.EXE that microsoft has made. https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=15201 or is there more to your question that I didn't understand?

Comment: I have to check for all user accounts and not just one. Secondly, my program is a service so I am little doubtful about LOCKOUT.EXE.
My main requirement is to get the Lockout status of each user on the domain and keep updating it (as for now, I am doing it for every 50 seconds).

Comment: Now pardon the fact that I am very partial to Powershell but http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/08/31/use-powershell-to-find-locked-out-user-accounts.aspx explains how to get the lockout status, with this you can have it poll every 50 seconds and just run as a background job, now I would recommend doing a HTML output too just for readability.

Comment: Is the service running on a domain controller?  (Is it the same domain controller you're looking at with the GUI?)  What security context is the service configured to run in?

Comment: @HarryJohnston ....yes on the DC
I am running it on my local machine to test it.
I have a few users with one of the accounts locked (user1).

Comment: @Luke thanks for the link... But I do not know how to poll it.
And the point of the creating a service is that the process has to be automatic.
I do not want the administrator to interact with the Powershell for every unlock operation

Comment: What security context is the service configured to run in?

Comment: @HarryJohnston If you are asking for the startup mode, it's Automatic
If not please elaborate

Comment: What account does it run under - the information in the "log on" tab in the Services control panel.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Local Service

Comment: I don't think that will give it enough access.  Try Network Service, or Local System.

Comment: It Worked Thanks!
Please Post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that when **UserPrincipal** object is used to get the lockout status of an account, the **entire LDAP Path** till the Organizational Unit(OU) in which the user is present should be provided as a parameter to the PrincipalContext along with the administrator login and password.

For example:

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "TRY.local"))
{
    using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
    {
        foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
        {
            DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
            string path = de.Path;
            var offset = path.IndexOf('/');
            offset = path.IndexOf('/', offset+1);
            offset = path.IndexOf('/', offset+1);
            path = path.Substring(offset+1);
            string user_id = Convert.ToString(de.Properties["samaccountname"].Value); 

            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,
                                       "TRY.local",
                                       path,
                                       "administrator",
                                       "password");
```

To use UserPrincipal, we now pass ctx and user_id as parameters to UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext, string) method.

The string path will finally contain: "CN=User,OU=USERS,OU=DEPARTMENT,DC=SERVER,DC=COM"

```
UserPrincipal user_locked = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, username);
if (user_locked != null) {
    if (user_locked.IsAccountLockedOut()){
       user_locked.UnlockAccount();                                         
    }
    user_locked.Dispose();
    Console.WriteLine("Unlocked");
}
ctx.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have valid network credentials in order to query the Active Directory.

When a service runs as Local Service, it does not have network credentials - it can only act on the local system.  If you need network credentials, configure the service to run as Network Service instead.  (If you need administrator access on the local machine, use Local System; this has network credentials and local administrator access.)

Services running as Network Service or Local System use the computer's Active Directory account when accessing the network, i.e., if the computer is named `PLUGH` then the username used to access the network is `PLUGH$`.